# Avoid leading $ or # when highlighting (double clicking) a command

Tags: feature-request

When you see a terminal command line entry on Stack Exchange sites like this

```
$ sudo apt-get install nginx
```

and double click to copy and paste into your own terminal, it brings with it the leading $ symbol (or # for that matter) whereas the desired behavior which is evident on [other non-Stack Exchange sites](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04) correctly ignores that leading $ or # ... should we implement this behavior here on Stack Exchange?

... not on code block just on `single line` entries ...the behavior change would occur on creation so the OP knows a leading $ or # is to be ignored.

Comment: Meh, would add loads of complexity - you'd have to be able to detect shell commands, tell them apart from other code blocks, and exclude the leading character only in those cases. Copy&pasters just need to be more careful.

Comment: One of my favorites: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19141512/17034 :)

Answer (score 17):

No thanks.

The effort required to style this properly, while preventing existing content from breaking all over the place hardly seems worth it, compared to pressing
<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> after pasting.

Or just click-and-drag select. It's quite intuitive.